# Comparing time and datetime in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am having difficulty comparing a time and datetime in rails.
 I have tried to do the following:
 `Post.where("created_at <= ?" time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))` (Here I am trying to find posts before a specific time of the day, regardless of date).
 This does not give me the expected result. Is there a way to format created_at to `"%H:%M:%S"` when doing the comparison?

Comment: Show your time of the day format with example

Comment: I have many posts which which are created on many different days. I wanted to find all the posts created before 6pm (Regardless of day). I ran the following: Post.where("created_at <= ?" time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")) and got no results even though all my posts are created before 6pm. For time, i did time = Time.now (6:33 pm right now)

Comment: This worked in postgres: Post.where("time(created_at) <= ?", time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
Thanks usmanali and user123!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it on query level. If you are using `mysql` you can follow this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_dates.asp) to choose the proper function that you require. `EXTRACT()` probably the most suitable for this.

However if you are using `postgresql` you can refer to this [link](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-datetime.html)

**Update**:

Here is an example of how to use it.

```
Post.where("DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%H:%M:%S') = ?" time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
```

Comment: Please add the relevant content from that link, or your question may be flagged as a link only answer.

Comment: This is `mysql` syntax. Are you using `mysql`?

Comment: Post.where("strftime(created_at,'%H:%M:%S')<= ?" ,time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")) still gives me no results.

Comment: btw time = 2015-05-26 18:36:58 +1000

Comment: Got it to work. Used the following in SQLite: Post.where("time(created_at) <= ?", time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this by doing following:

```
Post.where("TIME_FORMAT(created_at, '%H:%i:%s') <= ?", time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
```